# Inverse Matrix warning

Tags: matlab

When working in Matlab, I'm receiving this warning...

Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND =  6.001064e-34.

Here is my code...

```
clear
clc

P = [];
X = importdata('MSFT.csv',',');
P = [P X.data(:,5)];
X = importdata('ORCL.csv',',');
P = [P X.data(:,5)];
X = importdata('TEVA.csv',',');
P = [P X.data(:,5)];

TCR = {'msft', 'orcl', 'teva'};
N = 252;

r_ar = P(2:end, :)./P(1:end-1, :) - 1;
mu_d = mean(r_ar(1:end, :));
sigma_d = cov(r_ar(1:end, :));

mu_a = (mu_d + 1).^N -1;
sigma_a = 
   (sigma_d + (mu_d'+1)*(mu_d+1)).^N - (mu_d'+1).^N * (mu_d+1).^N;

rho =inv(sqrt(diag(diag(sigma_a))))*sigma_a*inv(sqrt(diag(diag(sigma_a))));

mu = mu_a';
S1 = inv(sigma_a);
```

The Warning is given for the line,

```
S1 = inv(sigma_a);
```

As I need to take the inverse of the sigma_a matrix is there any way to fix this warning? It's effecting other parts of my code.

Comment: The warning given when using `inv()` is not there for festive orange lines only. Read it, and act on it.

Comment: I'd like to add to the other comments that computing `inv` is usually not the right way to do things, simply because the inverse is not usually needed on its own. Typically, the inverse is used to solve a linear equation system etc, in which case, as mentioned, `mldivide` should be used. Sometimes you don't need the inverse, but a _pseudo-_ inverse (see also: `pinv`). In least squares, `(M.' * M) \ M.'` is used for non-square matrices. To conclude - we need to know what you are planning to do with the inverse matrices after they're computed, to know for sure which advice to give you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your workspace. Is `sigma_a` a `n x m` Matrix or is it just one integer value? Because I would expect that kind of a warning if it would be just a value. If not, could you post how `sigma_a` looks like?

Edit: 
use `mldivide` instead of `inv`

Comment: sigma_a is a 10x10 Matrix.

Comment: are there just double values?

Comment: this question is a duplicate. Apparently your matrix has no inverse. It's simply a mathematics problem, not a programmatical one. Use `mldivide` instead of `inv`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).